# How to include a list of terms (glossary) in a scholarly paper (IEEE format)?

Tags: academic-writing, resources, quotes, glossaries

I am currently writing my Bachelor's thesis and I have produced a list of terms that I plan on including in the attachments. The description of each term is directly copied from search engine results and different wikis. Is this legal? Is it OK to just write a notice saying the following?

> The descriptions below have been directly copied from search engine results.

I am using IEEE as the writing format. Is there a standard way to include a list of terms using IEEE?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE _Tøffelen_! If you have a moment, you may want to visit our [tour] and [help]. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cite definitions you have to mark them as citations and give a source. Otherwise you are plagiarising.

---

*Guidelines for formatting glossaries:*

- arrange entries alphabetically
- if the entry is a phrase, give it in its natural order (software development) rather than reversed (development, software)
- non-letter characters precede "a" in ordering
- show alternative spellings in parentheses
- if a term has more than one definition, number the definitions

*Example:*

> **question (Q).** (1) What you ask if you don't know the answer. (2) A post type on Stack Exchange sites.
>   *Contrast with:* **answer.** *See also:* **tour; off topic.**

*Explanation of example:*

In the example, "Q" is an alternative spelling for "question". "(1)" and "(2)" signify different definitions. After a linebreak, "Contrast with:" gives the opposing concept and "see also:" points out related definitions.

*Note:*

I only have access to an old guide from the early 90s, so the formatting may have changed. If you can verify or falsify, please comment or edit.

Comment: I was afraid of having to mark the entries as citations. Will it not look odd having marked every single entry of the list? I have never seen a list of terms looking like that, but maybe that is because the authors change the wording of the definitions.

Comment: @Tøffelen The only way to avoid citations is to rephrase all the definitions. What I do in such situations is find synonymous words, rearrange word order, and rewrite. – But if the definition you use is an official one (e.g. from a norm or standard), it might make sense to cite that and not rephrase it. – Maybe you want to talk to your supervisor about this?

Comment: Understood. I am meeting my supervisor in a few days, but thank you for clearing this up for me.